# TSQL - What is the proper order to joining tables?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join, join-hints

My google-fu and so-fu is failing me here, so I might as well ask.

I have many queries with multiple joins in them.

Within one query, I am joining header/item/details together, as well as looking up various bits of information for these records.

When joining, I try to keep things in order of how their related. E.g.: My header has two lookup tables, so I'll join to those before joining to my items table.

Is that correct?

Is it better to join to larger tables before lookup tables? Or vice-versa?

Should I use a `loop` hint when joining to small tables, and a `merge` hint when joining to openrowsets?

I'm sure the answer is "it depends", but some general guidelines to joining effectively and efficiently would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: In most cases you shouldn't need to specify the type of join (merge/loop/hash). If you do there are probably underlying problems that should be solved instead of the join hint band-aid.

Comment: Unless you know very well what you're doing, and you understand query execution plans, NEVER use query hints.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT: Based on your questions (and Kirk Woll's) comment, you should understand that the [order of your joins is aesthetic, and does not directly impact the resulting execution plan](http://sql-4-life.blogspot.com/2009/03/order-of-inner-joins.html).  The query optimizer will perform the joins in the most efficient order, and use the appropriate join operation the vast majority of the time without any hints needed.

When it comes the the aesthetics of your join order this is a little subjective, but I would say join your tables together in whatever order makes logical sense when reading through the query...  if you start with a @HeaderId, start with that table, and then `JOIN` to the children tables:

```
FROM
    Header h
    JOIN Items i ON h.HeaderId = i.HeaderId
    JOIN Details d ON i.ItemId = d.ItemId
WHERE
    h.HeaderId = @HeaderId
```

But, if you started your query with a @DetailId, I would join in the opposite order.

```
FROM
    Details d
    JOIN Items i ON d.ItemId = i.ItemId
    JOIN Header h ON i.HeaderId = h.HeaderId
WHERE
    d.DetailId = @DetailId
```

However, that's subjective and just my personal preference.

It becomes less subjective when you start to include `OUTER JOIN`s... try to structure your query to avoid any `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`s, and instead use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s.

Don't use join hints by default... in fact you'll almost never use them. The query optimizer does a very good job of choosing the optimal execution plan.  I've only encountered a single instance where I needed to provide a join hint to improve the plan... it helped drastically on the server that the query was running on at the time, but when the database was migrated to a different server, my join hint *destroyed* the performance of the query.  So, to reiterate, it is usually a bad idea to provide join hints.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is unaware that join order is irrelevant to the execution plan and is purely aesthetic?

Comment: @KirkWoll  That's a very good point that I overlooked... I'll clarify that in my answer.

Comment: @Kirk, that's exactly why I'm asking. The order isn't relevant at all?

Comment: @IronicMuffin - read up on [`OPTION (FORCE ORDER)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) - it's something you'd have to specifically ask for.

Comment: The order CAN affect the execution plan, at least if hints are used.

Answer (score 0):

The order is largely[1] aesthetic, but I do think it's useful to have a convention for both the order of the tables and the terms in the ON conditions, to avoid confusion.

Query hints are for exceptional cases only, and while you may find situations where you need to use them (typically sacrificing performance to reduced concurrency problems) you should always try to find a more robust way to fix the problem.

[1]
I know of one case where the order does matter:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A (id),
  name varchar
);

SELECT *
FROM A
INNER LOOP JOIN B on A.id = B.a_id;

SELECT *
FROM B
INNER LOOP JOIN A on A.id = B.a_id;
```

The first select does two index scans, the second does a scan and a seek. This is another good reason to avoid hints.